# How to optimize this mysql query - %a% or

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id AS userId,u.type AS userType 
FROM User AS u,Personal AS p,Company AS c 
WHERE (p.realName LIKE '%adf%' AND u.type=1 AND u.id=p.userId) 
OR (c.name LIKE '%grge%' AND u.id=c.userId) 
LIMIT 0 , 10000
```

Comment: Please post your explain plan.

Comment: `LIKE` query with both wildcards performs a full table scan. Don't use both wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your query as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id AS userId,u.type AS userType 
FROM User AS u inner join Personal AS p on u.id=p.userId
               inner join Company AS c on u.id=c.userId
where p.realName LIKE '%adf%' or c.name LIKE '%grge%'
LIMIT 0 , 10000
```

*Try to avoid comma seperated JOINS*

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be doing a quite hideous cross join, and then selectively narrowing down the records in the WHERE clause.

It is probably better to do 2 queries and union the results together. Each query can do one proper join. It is still going to have to access one column using the LIKE, and with a leading wild card that is not going to be quick (it can't use indexes).

```
SELECT u.id AS userId,
        u.type AS userType 
FROM User AS u
INNER JOIN Personal AS p
ON u.id = p.userId
WHERE p.realName LIKE '%adf%' 
AND u.type = 1 
UNION
SELECT u.id AS userId,
        u.type AS userType 
FROM User AS u
INNER JOIN Company AS c 
ON u.id=c.userId
WHERE c.name LIKE '%grge%' 
LIMIT 0 , 10000
```